# Regex Python : extracting special content

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to list some notifications for expired client certificates, then send an email including the client name and the date of expiration.

```
r = self._s.get(self.url)
if r.status_code == 200:
        pass
    else : 
        return None
    for i in re.finditer('<a id="[A-Z0-9]+" href="/ui/partycfg/remote/Certificate\?partyId=([0-9]+).*?" title=".*?">(.*?)</a>', r.text):
        print i.group(1) + ": " + i.group(2)
```

here i can retrieve the list by using **i.groupe(2)**
for example, the list is like :

```
partner1's certificate 'partner certif1' expired on 08/23/17
partner2's certificate 'partner certif2' expired on 02/14/18
```

How can i extract the partner name and the date.
Thank you

Comment: You need to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new problems into the code you are showing to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that

```
(.*?)'s.*((?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{2})
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5X0269/2)

1. Get Partner name in group 1
2. Get Date in group 2

Sample Code:

```
import re 
regex = r"(.*?)'s.*((?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{2})"
test_str = ("partner1's certificate 'partner certif1' expired on 08/23/17\n"
    "partner2's certificate 'partner certif2' expired on 02/14/18")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1));
    print(match.group(2));
```

[Run Code](https://ideone.com/GJZ4rX)

Comment: That's exaclty what i want thank!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, regex is overkill for this. Regex is very slow compared to string slicing:

```
data = """partner1's certificate 'partner certif1' expired on 08/23/17
partner2's certificate 'partner certif2' expired on 02/14/18"""

for line in data.split('\n'):
    name = line[:line.find("'")]
    date = line[-8:]
    print "name:", name, "date:", date
```

Output:

```
name: partner1 date: 08/23/17
name: partner2 date: 02/14/18
```

[Try online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQ1MzX3JVQkNmaDQ)

Comment: Thank you very much